# How to change max_connection_lifetime of python driver in py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I need to increase `max_connection_lifetime` of python driver in py2neo
but i cannot find anyway in documents to do that

I there a way to increase the `max_connection_lifetime` in `py2neo` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no way to do this, as py2neo does not wrap the official driver, and there exists no equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The worst thing to do is use py2neo for a serious application, it gives a lot of issues with the connections, closing them. It is better use the official driver